# Solving a system of first order differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

I've got a set of equations of motion here (describing the interior of a charged black hole, if you're interested). It's just four first order ODEs, so *Mathematica* should be  able to solve this easily but I'm not really sure how to interpret the errors it's giving me.

Here is my code:

```
Q = .0025;
M = 1;
bi = .127;
xi = Q/(4*3.1416);

deqns = {eps1'[T] == 32*3.1416/bi (eps3[T]*a3[T]/(eps1[T]) + a1[T]), 
         eps3'[T] == 16*3.1416 (eps3[T]*a1[T]/eps1[T]),
         a1'[T] == 32*3.1416/bi*(eps3[T]*a3[T]*a1[T]/(eps1[T])^2),
         a3'[T] ==  16*3.1416 (a3[T]*a1[T]/(eps1[T]*bi) -  3.1416*bi*(xi^2 + 4)/eps3[T]^2)};

T0 = M + (M^2 - Q^2)^.5 - .0001;
Tf = M - (M^2 - Q^2)^.5 + .0001;

B0 = 2 M/T0 - 1 - Q^2/T0^2;
Bdot0 = 2 Q^2/T0^3 - 2 M/T0^2;
N0 = T0^2/(Abs[T0^2*B0])^.5;

ics = {eps3[T0] == T0^2,
       eps1[T0] == (T0^2*B0)^.5,
       a1[T0] == -bi/N0,
       a3[T0] == -bi*Bdot0/(2*N0*(B0)^.5)};

sol = NDSolve[{deqns, ics}, {eps1, eps3, a1, a3}, {T, Tf, T0}]
```

To which *Mathematica* replies with:

> NDSolve::nlnum: The function value {112.87,5.21436,-3554.23,6.38373 +16 pi} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {4} at {T, a1[T], a3[T], eps1[T], eps3[T], (a1^[Prime])[T], (a3^[Prime])[T], (eps1^[Prime])[T], 16 pi} = {1.9999, -.000449047, 0.0158774, 0.0141418, 3.99959, 0., 0., 0., 0.}.
>
> NDSolve::icfail: Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function within specified tolerances. Try giving initial conditions for both values and derivatives of the functions. >>

These error messages are disturbing to me for two reasons:

1. I'm not sure why there's a `16 pi` in there. Whenever I put in π, I put it in as 3.1516, not as a symbol like what appears in that error message.
2. It's asking that I "Try giving initial conditions for both values and derivatives of the functions" but these are first order differential equations! I should not need to give initial values of the derivative, only the function.

Can anyone spot what went wrong? Am I just using `NDSolve` wrong?

Comment: It's working fine for me. You might have a pre-defined value somewhere. Restart your Kernel. I get solutions (except a singularity at  T = 1.9998948863867934 that you might be able to fix with different methods)

Comment: Oh, awesome! I just copy pasted into a new worksheet and it works. I'm new to mathematica, is there an easier way to restart my Kernel?

The singularity at T=1.9998948863867934 is fine, that's the event horizon of the black hole

Comment: @Mason You can use the menu: "Evaluation" -> "Quit Kernel" -> "Local" will quit the kernel. You can also use the `Quit[]` command.

Comment: @Mason  Is it fine?  Since NDSolve is integrating from the outside in, the domain of integration is essentially nil.

Comment: Well there are other ways, I know of `Clear` and `Remove`.  Maybe read the "Lingering Definitions: when calculations go bad" part of this link: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users
(btw this link is awesome, read it!)

Comment: @bbgodfrey Aw crap, you're right. This isn't behaving afterall. So, I only want it to go from T=Tf to T=T0, though my 'initial' conditions are for T=T0.

Is that a problem in mathematica?

Comment: I've tried plotting eps_3[T] using the command Plot[eps3[T] /. sol, {T, Tf, T0}] and sometime is definitely wrong. eps3 should go as T^2.

Comment: @Mason  This is a mathematics issue, not a Mathematica issue.  You are solving an initial value problem, beginning at T0.  To circumvent the apparent singularity at the event horizon, I recommend that you change coordinates to remove it, which I know is possible from my work on the Kerr metric 45 years ago.

Comment: @Mason   I should add that any results you get from `Plot[eps3[T] /. sol, {T, Tf, T0}]` are meaningless, because `sol` is valid only very near `T = 2`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I think you're right, something must have gone wrong in my Poisson Brackets.  The coordinate transformation is not necessary since I only care about what's going on inside the horizon. I had hoped that what was wrong was just that Mathematica was evolving the solution the wrong way and hitting the coordinate singularity but that seems to not be the case.